# Biztalk/XSLT - map belonging segments without any correlating

Tags: xml, xslt, mapping, biztalk, biztalk-mapper

I have the following xml `(HL7)` message.

```
`<OBR>One</OBR>`
`<ZCT>Two</ZCT>`
`<OBR>Three</OBR>`
`<ZCT>Four</ZCT>`
```

I need to map these to another XML like this:

```
`<Number>`
`<One>One</One>`
`<Two>Two</Two>`
`</Number>`
`<Number>`
`<One>Three</One>`
`<Two>Four</Two>`
`</Number>`
```

Nothing in these fields correlates. I can rely on the structure/order of the fields but that´s it.
So I need to map all the OBR fields, together with the following ZCT fields, before the next OBR occurs.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: Is that the complete HL7-message? Or is this just a part of sequences like that?
Can you make one xml with the two xml-fragments into one so xslt can access both? I.e  <proces><hl7>The content of the hl7 xml</hl7><other>The content of the other xml</other></proces>

Comment: How does the resulting xml look like?

Answer (score 0):

If you could combine both xml-fragments into one like i.e. this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proces>
  <hl7>
    <OBR>One</OBR>
    <ZCT>Two</ZCT>
    <OBR>Three</OBR>
    <ZCT>Four</ZCT>
  </hl7>
  <other>
    <Number>
      <One>One</One>
      <Two>Two</Two>
    </Number>
    <Number>
      <One>Three</One>
      <Two>Four</Two>
    </Number>
  </other>
</proces>
```

Then the following xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">
  
  <xsl:template match="/proces">
    <result>
      <xsl:variable name="hl7Props" select="hl7/*"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="other/*/*">
        <newProp>
          <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="$hl7Props[$pos]"/>
        </newProp>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </result>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

gives this result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
  <newProp>
    <One>One</One>
    <OBR>One</OBR>
  </newProp>
  <newProp>
    <Two>Two</Two>
    <ZCT>Two</ZCT>
  </newProp>
  <newProp>
    <One>Three</One>
    <OBR>Three</OBR>
  </newProp>
  <newProp>
    <Two>Four</Two>
    <ZCT>Four</ZCT>
  </newProp>
</result>
```